# 2D histogram with several colorbars

Tags: python, numpy, histogram, heatmap, contour

I have 3 datasets that I would like to show in the same 2D plane. Because things get a bit crowded when using seaborn's kdeplot, I would like to use some sort of heatmap. Is it possible to have a single 2D histogram or heatmap in python with 3 different colorbars (one for each data set) or with one composite colorbar? Here's an example of the contours.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

x1, x2, x3 = np.random.normal(0.2, 0.1, 100), np.random.normal(0.7, 0.1, 100), np.random.normal(0.5, 0.1, 100)
y1, y2, y3 = np.random.normal(0.2, 0.1, 100), np.random.normal(0.2, 0.1, 100), np.random.normal(0.5, 0.1, 100)
plt.figure()
sns.kdeplot(x1, y1, color="blue")
sns.kdeplot(x2, y2, color='green')
sns.kdeplot(x3, y3, color="red")

plt.show()
```

[image: Example contours]

The way I see it is a white or black plane with red, green and blue hotspots for the different data sets, but I don't know how you overlap these kinds of heatmaps, e.g. plt.hist2d() or plt.hexbin() or plt.imshow(). I already defined a custom colormap that I thought could be useful, but I'm not sure how to assign the different datasets to the main colors of the map...

```
cmap2 = ["white", "blue", "green", "red"]
cmap2_arr = np.array([list(mpl.colors.to_rgba(c)) for c in cmap2])  # This converts the names to rgba tuples
map_object = mpl.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list(name='mymap', colors=cmap2_arr)
plt.register_cmap(cmap=map_object)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to plot the 2D contour plot of your data in 3D as follows.

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.path import Path
import matplotlib.patches as patches

fig    = plt.figure()
ax     = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')

x      = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
X, Y   = np.meshgrid(x, x)
levels = np.linspace(-0.1, 0.4, 100)  #(z_min,z_max,number of contour),

x1, x2, x3 = np.random.normal(0.2, 0.1, 100), np.random.normal(0.7, 0.1, 100), np.random.normal(0.5, 0.1, 100)

y1, y2, y3 = np.random.normal(0.2, 0.1, 100), np.random.normal(0.7, 0.1, 100), np.random.normal(0.5, 0.1, 100)

a=0
b=1
c=2

def f(a, b):
   return np.sin(a*X)*np.sin(b*Y)

Z1 = a + f(2, 4)
Z2 = b + f(3, 4)
Z3 = c + f(4, 5)

# following is for changing default cmap
# value in plt.contourf
# cmap = plt.get_cmap('inferno')

plt.contourf(x1, y1, Z1, levels=a+levels)
plt.contourf(x2, y2, Z2, levels=b+levels)
plt.contourf(x3, y3, Z3, levels=c+levels)

plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

[image: 2D Contour plot]

Some useful references

- [2D contour plot](https://www.javaer101.com/en/article/36986140.html)
- [Contour plot of irregularly spaced data](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/irregulardatagrid.html#sphx-glr-gallery-images-contours-and-fields-irregulardatagrid-py)